# Sublime Text 4 hide title bar

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm running i3 window manager on linux and my sublime text was just updated to version 4.

Now there is a (rather obnoxiously large) title bar above the menu which shows the current file path that I cannot get rid of. I assume this is non standard since all other programs on my machine don't show a title bar due to i3.

Distraction free mode and fullscreen mode hide it, but that defeats the purpose of a tiling window manager.

How can I disable this?

I can see the option

```
"themed_title_bar": false,
```

but this doesn't hide the title bar. I don't see a toggle option either like the menu or status bars.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `themed_title_bar` setting controls whether the theme you're using has the ability to change the color of the title bar or not to match the theme (for themes that support it). On Windows this also has the effect of hiding the menu and placing it in a rolled up "hamburger menu" in the title bar.

On Linux, there is also support for custom title bars irrespective of that which only enables itself if it detects that you're using an appropriate window manager. In cases where it detects incorrectly (you want the feature but it's not enabled) or you want to remove it because you don't want it (which is sounds like you're running into here), you need to adjust the value of this setting:

```json
    "gtk_client_side_window_decorations": true,
```

Setting it to `true` turns on the feature, and `false` turns it off; you must restart Sublime after changing the setting for it to take effect.

Comment: Not working in ST4 and Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Are you trying to turn it on or turn it off?

Comment: I want to turn off. I have less screen space so I want the menu to go to the menu bar like in macOS without showing the native window title bar.

Comment: Sublime only supports having no explicit title bar when you tell it to run fullscreen or your window manager uses windows with no decorations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The given answer did not work for me on Linux Mint. Turns out that hitting F11 to go into full screen mode properly hides the title bar. You only have to add this to the sublime settings to make that state persist after the program closes: `"remember_full_screen": true`